# Java - indentify the String which is have special character at the last

Tags: java, string

Having a list of String while iterating am trying to identify the last character of the String containing any special character.

for eg:

```
Apple,
Apple
Apple(
Apples.
Apples
```

Expected Result :

```
Apple
Apples
```

Please find my code below, am just replacing the special character with "" (empty) as of now., But i want to remove the string itself.

```
for (TermSuggestion.Entry entry : termSuggestion.getEntries()) { 
    for (TermSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry) { 
        String suggestText = option.getText().string();
        String result = suggestText.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]()","");
        System.out.println("Print String--->  "+result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Character.isAlphabetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) to work out whether its a special character or not. You can use [`String.charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get the last character.

```
for (TermSuggestion.Entry entry : termSuggestion.getEntries())
{ 
    for (TermSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry)
    { 
        String suggestText = option.getText().string();
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(suggestText.charAt(suggestText.length()))
        {
            System.out.println("Print String--->  "+result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `.*[a-z]$` to filter only words that end with a small case/lower case character.

Comment: a _smallercase_ character, to be exact

Comment: @Michael Some countries (or lets say locales :)) do use small case for lower case

Comment: @Yogesh_D It's called 'lowercase' because printing press operators had different sets of blocks for capitals and non-capitals. The non-capitals were used most often, and so were kept *lower* because they were easier to reach. It's nothing to do with the size of the characters

Comment: @Michael Sure, i mean _lowercase_, i guess its too early in the morning - i did not realise it

Comment: @Michael TIL why lower case. need submit this to r/TodayILearned :)

Answer (score 0):

To *remove* the string, first of all your collection must be modifiable. In your case it's  `termSuggestion`, so make sure it is, or make a copy if not.
Then, use an `Iterator` and iterate by calling `hasNext()` and `next()`. Once you hit the string you want to remove, call the `remove()` method. See the Iterator documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Following code with Streams and apache.commons.lang3.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apples.", "Apples");
String[] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
List<String> result = strings.stream().filter(item -> StringUtils.endsWithAny(item, alphabet)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I guess using regex and matches if a little easier than typing down all characters

Comment: We can obviously mix all solutions provided here to implement the sexiest one :)